# What is the "Other" account in LightDM?

Tags: 11.10, lightdm

I use Ubuntu Oneiric and I would like to know what is the account named Other for? It does not appear in the user manager. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 12):

*Other* actually isn't an account, but an item that will allow you to explicitly type in a user name. Sometimes you don't want to show users in the greeter, but you still want to be able to log in with them. That's when you'd choose *Other*.

About removing that entry: I don't think it's possible. Seems it's hard-coded in the greeter:

```
...
else
{
    foreach (var user in LightDM.UserList.get_instance ().users)
    {
        var label = user.real_name;
        if (user.real_name == "")
            label = user.name;
        user_list.add_entry (user.name, label, null);
    }
    if (greeter.has_guest_account_hint)
        user_list.add_entry ("*guest", _("Guest Account"), null);
    user_list.add_entry (null, _("Other..."));
}
...
```